# Java ReStart application command in programmatically

Tags: java

Is there in Java any command or proccedure that I can restart my appliation itself?

I developed a Java desktop application, but after some time it's going hang. I don't know why, so I want to restart my application itself. Is it possible?

Comment: How would a application which hangs do anything? Also you should use a debugger to find out why it hangs.

Comment: this is a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3854997/how-to-restart-java-application-remembering-its-command-line-arguments. The accepted answer is the way to go.

Comment: This is why software sucks these days. Sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're doing it wrong. Find out why your application hangs by debugging it or adding some logging code, and after further examination fix the problem.

My answer is a bit general, but to make an analogy; you're trying to open the front door of your house using a sledgehammer without checking your pockets first.

Answer (score 1):

It should be possible by using `Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);`, but I think the better solution here would be to find the reason why your application hangs after a while. Just because your application starts to hang after, for example, two hours doesn't mean that it didn't already ill behave a long time before.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend to try hard and fix the problem that causes your app hang. But if you still want to restart it I think the only way is running a new instance and killing the old one:

```
RunTime.getRuntime().exec("java My_Program");
System.exit(0);
```