# How to restart the application after an error?

Tags: java, process, restart, uncaught-exception

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [how to restart java application, remembering its command line arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3854997/how-to-restart-java-application-remembering-its-command-line-arguments)

Hi, I'm developing an editor in Java and I want it to provide the ability to restart the whole application after an error.

I set the exception handler using `Thread.setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler`, and I'm displaying a message box there, it's easy. What I need is to somehow close the application and then start it again with the same file.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with

> Runtime.getRuntime().exec("java -jar "location.of.your.jar");

To get jar location:

> ```
> public static File getJarFile(Class main) {
>     try {
>         File f = new File(main.getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation().toURI());
>         return f;
>     } catch (URISyntaxException ex) {
>         return null;
>     }
> }
> ```

Answer (score 0):

Start the application by invoking `Runtime.exec("my_startup_command");`
Don't wait for termination, don't read the Processoutput.

Answer (score 0):

What we do when we want to wake up in the early morning? We tell someone in our house to wake us up or we set up an alarm. So the same can be applied to this scenario. Make a completely independent application from your main application which will work as the "Invoker" for your main application. And under the Restart command, just start the invoker app with all the command line arguments and exit your main app. Then after some time (whatever time you set), your invoker app will start your main app.